# What is byte fixed size length?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers

I have to connect and send a message to a server. It needs the Message Length and the manual states:

> message length: fixed size (4 bytes)

How do you get a fixed length size in javascript/node.js?  Suppose the message is: "Hello, hand shake."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a buffer:

```
var buffer = new Buffer(4, 'hex');
buffer.write('aabbaaaa'); // 10101010 10111011 10101010 10101010
```

docs:
http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer

useful nodejitsu article:
http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/buffers/how-to-use-buffers